# "Help" button, which is connecting to chat with active moderator

Tags: feature-request

I propose to add a help button on our page, which is connecting to chat with currently active moderator. Many users have troubles creating posts, answering questions, want to ask about something and discuss about that with a real person in live chat. This button may be located e.g under ignored and favorite tags on main page, and above similar questions in new question window.

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time an April 1st joke becomes a reality. Bring back the Expert!

Comment: Moderators are busy enough, you know, moderating?

Comment: "If this is an emergency, please hang up and dial Meta"

Comment: This is not a call center. The only way for this to work is if your request for a live moderator goes into a queue, and we start *paying moderators*.

Comment: This would result in moderators drowning in "my code doesnt work plz help" requests.

Comment: @perhapsPekka Or, it would result in moderators quitting. I guess after the "plz help" requests. ;)

Comment: @Andrew the first draft of my comment envisioned a moderator ending his life in a rather dramatic and messy manner. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Moderators, especially the SO moderators are rather busy. Having hundreds of users trying to chat with them would quickly overwhelm them. There is a very limited number of moderators, and they don't scale well. We can't arbitrarily increase the number of moderators without causing other problems. Moderators should not be required for common tasks, they just don't scale well enough, the community should be able to handle those.

That said, chat is a very inefficient medium and I strongly oppose using it to support users that can't manage to formulate a decent question. A well written question is so much better than a chat where you have to ask for every single detail. A question also forces the users to put some minimum effort into writing a coherent post, we shouldn't make the barrier to entry even lower than it currently is.

Comment: Also, this would very quickly be abused. For example, I've declined at least a dozen "plz answer this, it's urgent" style flags over the last few hours alone. People wouldn't use this to get help on posting their question, they'd use it to ask moderators to answer them. There's a reason why many chat rooms on SO require approval before joining them.

Comment: Woosh! A reversal!

Answer (score 10):

Users who have problems using the site can post on meta with their question and get help from a moderator, or just any knowledgeable community member, quite quickly.  The site is quite active.

That said, you are more than welcome to go to the meta's chat service (linked at the top of the page) where there are likely to be some mods active and that can help you with your problems.

I see no need to *prohibit* knowledgeable and helpful community members from answering such questions first.

Answer (score 4):

> Many users have troubles creating posts, answering questions, want to ask about something and discuss about that with a real person in live chat.

1. Read the help pages first. That will explain how the site works and how anyone with two cents should use it.
2. When your reputation in any SE site is above 20, you get access to chat, where you can ask people what you want. The reason about the reputation requirement is explained also in the help page.

Bottom line - read the help page. Better yet, read the About page and get a free badge (cookies were unavailable at the moment).